# How can we uninstall a module directly from the database?

Tags: installation

I am trying to find a way to uninstall a Drupal 8 module directly from database.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

1. `drush pm-uninstall`.
2. If you have entities in your module, write a query in your module to first delete all entities of your particular entity type. Once deleted, remove that file where you have written annotation for your entity, create a backup for use later. Except `.info.yml` file and `.install file`, remove all files.

Now you can easily un-install that module. Once un-installed, put all your backed up files into your module folder again, install your module and go!